# How to inject resource Class instance in Spring using Dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, aws-sdk

I am new to Spring. There is a case for which I have written a Class that implements the AutoCloseable interface. Now I want to use it as dependency injection.

My concern is if I use @Autowired and later use it in function will Spring automatically close the resource object after ending the scope or any exception?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/profile")
public class ProfileController {

   private Daws haws;


   @Autowired
   public ProfileController(Daws haws) {
      this.haws = haws;
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/images/{userId}/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public void image(@PathVariable Integer userId, @PathVariable String publicUrl, @PathVariable String fileName, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
      try{
         S3Object image = haws.getProfileImage(userId, fileName, request);

         response.setContentType(image.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
         response.setHeader("ETag",image.getObjectMetadata().getETag());
         response.setHeader("Cache-Control",image.getObjectMetadata().getCacheControl());
         response.setHeader("Last-Modified",image.getObjectMetadata().getLastModified().toString());
         IOUtils.copy(image.getObjectContent(), response.getOutputStream());
      }catch (Exception e) {
         if(e instanceof AmazonS3Exception){
            //....
            //....
            response.setStatus(statusCode);
         }
     }
 }

//Daws class
public class Daws implements AutoCloseable{
    public S3Object getProfileImage(int userId, String fileName, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ParseException, AmazonS3Exception{

        S3Object image = ....;

        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

I am now doing it this way. Please tell me is it fine or the resource is leaking. If yes what can I do then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Spring managed beans you can either implement [DisposableBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-disposablebean) interface or use [@PreDestroy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) annotation. Spring will call the destroy method when application context is destroyed.

If you need to create and close the object on each method invocation you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Will I have to instantiate the object using "new" keyword to implement this using try-with-resource ?

Comment: No you are not required to use the new keyword. You need to have a local variable for the try-with-resources block though. For your example you can do    try (Daws closableHaws = haws) {/**your code*/}. Or if you need a more precise control over when and what should be closed used the finally block.

Comment: Yea I have done that it was also closing the resource. Apart from this I was able to close it by using finally in the old fashioned way. If I use finally then I don't need to store it in local variable. Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0):

AutoCloseable will never be closed by Spring if you don't use `try-with-resources` or explicitly call `close()`

> void close()
>              throws Exception
>   Closes this resource, relinquishing any underlying resources. This method is invoked automatically on objects managed by the try-with-resources statement.

from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)