# How can I inject an autocloseable resource

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, java-7, try-with-resources

How can I inject an Autocloseable resource, which ideally should be used with Java 7's try with resource feature? Is the following code below using Lombok correct?

`AppConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig{
     @Bean
     public AutoCloseable myFtpClient(){
       return new MyFtpClient(); // My custom FTP Client.
     }
}
```

`Sample.java` below:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Sample {

    @NonNull
    private final AutoCloseable autoCloseable;

    public void execute() {
        try (final AutoCloseable ac = autoCloseable) {
            ac.connect() // do the real stuff 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("{}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover if I cannot inject the autocloseable object, how can I unit test the above class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inject resource Class instance in Spring using Dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412350/how-to-inject-resource-class-instance-in-spring-using-dependency-injection)